# Can standalone lightning apps be offline?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

My requirement is to have a lightweight application which I can give to my users which work offline and on mobile outside IP ranges.

I was able to achieve it via a visualforce page with appCache on Force.com sites.

I want to use Lightning standalone application for this specific development by using `ltng:allowGuestAccess` (spring17) and `appCache=true`.

When I try that and launch my application offline it refreshes continuously.[image: continuous refresh with standalone lightning app]

I see a similar behavior when I use Visualforce and Lightning out. Is there some way I can get my Lightning components to run offline.

I am able to get it running offline if my solution is entirely on visualforce with help of offline storage libraries (localforage)

please suggest.